# Why isn't this LINQ Group By aggregating the rows in vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table that has a 2 part key; an ID column, and a version number.  I'm trying to select 'only the latest version' of the records.

I'm trying to use the expression style of LINQ, to achieve a GROUP BY, and pull out the aggregate MAX value of the Version.  **However no aggregation is taking place**.

**Summarized Code:**

```
From C In Credentials

Group Join ....
Group Join ....

Group C.CredentialID, NE.ClientID, C.Version By 
     NE.ClientID, C.CredentialID Into CGroup = Group
From CG In CGroup

Select New With {
    .ClientID = CG.ClientID,
    .CredentialID = CG.CredentialID,
    .MaxVersion = CGroup.Max(Function(p) p.Version)
}
```

**Actual Results:**

```
ClientID CredentialID MaxVersion
1196     1            3 
1196     1            3 
1196     1            3 
1196     2            1
```

**Desired Results:**

```
ClientID CredentialID MaxVersion
1196     1            3 
1196     2            1
```

**Also tried, same results:**

```
Group C By Key = New With 
     {Key NE.ClientID, Key C.CredentialID} Into CGroup = Group
From CG In CGroup

Select New With {
     .ClientID = Key.ClientID,
     .CredentialID = Key.CredentialID,
     .MaxVersion = CGroup.Max(Function(p) p.Version)
}
```

I'm looking for a solution that does not involves creating custom classes with matching properties and custom sorting / grouping functions, and does not use the lambda expressions on the tail end of the query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
From CG In CGroup
```

This line calls Queryable.SelectMany and unpacks the groups.  Don't unpack your groups!

Remove that line and end with:

```
Select New With {
     .ClientID = CGroup.Key.ClientID,
     .CredentialID = CGroup.Key.CredentialID,
     .MaxVersion = CGroup.Max(Function(p) p.Version)
}
```

Comment: Can I ask where you learned this important nugget of information?

Comment: Mainly from pouring over the msdn references for System.Linq.Enumerable and System.Linq.Queryable .  Don't be afraid of using the lambda syntax, the compiler turns what you write into that anyway.

Comment: I'm not exactly an enthusiastic convert to LINQ, and translating from SQL seems even more confusing...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the anonymous class defined for the key does not evaluate equality in the way you like. Instead, you can use a Tuple for the key:

```
From C In Credentials
... 
Group C.CredentialID, NE.ClientID, C.Version By key = 
       New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)(NE.ClientID, C.CredentialID) 
       Into CGroup = Group 
Select New With {
       .ClientID = key.Item1, 
       .CredentialID = key.Item2, 
       .MaxVersion = CGroup.Max(Function(p) p.Version)
}
```

Comment: I got this error at runtime and in LINQPAD:  "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: Oh, I just tried with Linq2Objects. I fear, unless you want to misuse other classes for that case, you will have to create a small class that can hold the key.

Comment: Linq to objects is irrelevant.  This is an EF query.  The query is sent to the database and not evaluated with .net instances.  There are no anonymous group key instances and their equality semantics are not used.

Comment: Even though it didn't solve my answer, I learned something new (vb.net tuples), and hopefully anyone else reading this can quickly rule out trying to make tuples work if they are using LINQ2EF.  +1